# How to resolve an empty list in velocity template?

Tags: velocity

I am using velocity template to handle a list.

```
#set($end = $POSEX.size() - 1)

ITEM           QUANTITY       UOM        PRICE         AMOUNT  

#foreach($i in [0..$end])

$display.cell($ITEMNO.get($i),15)$display.cell($QUANTITY.get($i),15)$display.cell($UOM.get($i),11)$display.cell($PRICE.get($i),14)$display.cell($AMOUNT.get($i),14)
$display.cell($MATRNO.get($i),20)$DESCRIPTION.get($i)

#end
```

But if `$ITEMNO` list is coming as empty. How to handle this as it will throw

> Invocation of method 'get'in class java.util.ArrayList threw exception.

Comment: Why don't you want to make an #if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#if (($ITEMNO) && ($ITEMNO.size() > 0))

#end
```

This code verify if `$ITEMNO` is not null and has elements.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got it resolved by using

```
#if($ITEMNO.size()!=0)
$display.cell($ITEMNO.get($i),15)
#{else}
$display.cell("",15)
#end.
```

Comment: well, that is what I suggested :) to use #if statement